# How to throw variable out of loop to another loop in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a loop inside another loop and trying to throw a variable out of inner loop but i get error:

> addorder:524 Uncaught ReferenceError: productPrice is not defined

This is my success ajax code that runs these loops:

````
success: function(data) {

    // تبدیل اطلاعات قیمت و موتور ها به جیسون
    const objofproduct = JSON.parse(data.products);
    const objofprice = JSON.parse(data.prices);
    console.log(objofprice[0].productCode);;
    // صفر لحاظ کردن متغیر فرضی
    var i = 0;
    
    // لوپ تولید آیتم هر شهر
    jQuery.each(objofproduct, function(){
        
        var e = 0;
        jQuery.each(objofprice, function() {
            console.log(objofprice[e].id);
            if(objofprice[e].productCode == objofproduct[i].productCode) {
                var productPrice = [objofprice[e].basePrice];
                console.log(productPrice[0]);
                var z = z + 1;
            } else {
                console.log('برای محصول قیمت تعریف نشده است');
                var z = z + 1;
            };
        });
        console.log(productPrice[0]);
        // تعریف کد اچ تی ام ال قابل تکرار در صفحه
        var productitem = "<div class='mymotor grid grid-cols-3 p-4 my-4 rounded-lg border-2 hover:bg-slate-100'> <div class='col-span-1 pl-4'><img class='w-full rounded-lg hover:shadow' src='"+objofproduct[i].imageUrl+"'/></div><div class='descriptionbig m-3 col-span-2 grid grid-cols-1 flex h-min'><div class='name pb-6 col-span-1 ltr w-full flex items-center h-fit font-semibold antialiased'><div class='w-2/3 flex justify-end'>"+objofproduct[i].brandName+" "+objofproduct[i].modelName+" "+objofproduct[i].tipName+"</div><div class='w-1/3 productcode font-light text-sm flex justify-start'>"+objofproduct[i].productCode+"</div></div><div class='text-lg'><b>» رنگ:</b> "+objofproduct[i].colorName+" <br> <b>» توضیحات:</b> "+objofproduct[i].description+"<br>"+productPrice[0]+"</div></div></div>";
        // تعیین ساختار مادر ایکس و کدی که باید هر بار اضافه شود
        $("#productx").append(productitem);
        // افزودن یک عدد به متغیر فرضی
        i = i + 1 ;
    })
    // پایان لوپ آیتم هر شهر

},
// پایان موفقیت```
````

I tried to set array for variable but it wasn't successful.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is directly related to AJAX?

Comment: @NicoHaase it's related to jQuery that i used in ajax

Comment: This is probably what you're after: [how to return from an async call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks, solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you use `var` to declare a variable, it will be scoped to the function where it is declared.

To access `productPrice` in the outer loop, you need to declare it outside the scope of the inner loop.

The relevant part of your code becomes

```
jQuery.each(objofproduct, function(){
    var productPrice; // productPrice is declared here to make it accessible in both loops
    var e = 0;
    jQuery.each(objofprice, function() {
        console.log(objofprice[e].id);
        if(objofprice[e].productCode == objofproduct[i].productCode) {
            var productPrice = [objofprice[e].basePrice];
            console.log(productPrice[0]);
            var z = z + 1;
        } else {
            console.log('برای محصول قیمت تعریف نشده است');
            var z = z + 1;
        };
    });
    console.log(productPrice[0]);
   // rest of code..
```

Comment: this code returns undefined in last console.log

Answer (score 0):

I used ***result*** in jQuery loop and this is final code:

```
// در صورت موفقیت
        success: function(data) {

            // تبدیل اطلاعات قیمت و موتور ها به جیسون
            const objofproduct = JSON.parse(data.products);
            const objofprice = JSON.parse(data.prices);
            console.log(objofprice[0].productCode);;
            // صفر لحاظ کردن متغیر فرضی
            var i = 0;
            
            // لوپ تولید آیتم هر شهر
            jQuery.each(objofproduct, function(){
                var productPrice;
                var e = 0;
                jQuery.each(objofprice, function() {
                    console.log(objofprice[e].id);
                    if(objofprice[e].productCode == objofproduct[i].productCode) {
                        var productPrice = [objofprice[e].basePrice];
                        result = productPrice;
                        console.log(productPrice[0]);
                        var z = z + 1;
                    } else {
                        console.log('برای محصول قیمت تعریف نشده است');
                        
                    };
                });
                console.log(result[0]);
                // تعریف کد اچ تی ام ال قابل تکرار در صفحه
                var productitem = "<div class='mymotor grid grid-cols-3 p-4 my-4 rounded-lg border-2 hover:bg-slate-100'> <div class='col-span-1 pl-4'><img class='w-full rounded-lg hover:shadow' src='"+objofproduct[i].imageUrl+"'/></div><div class='descriptionbig m-3 col-span-2 grid grid-cols-1 flex h-min'><div class='name pb-6 col-span-1 ltr w-full flex items-center h-fit font-semibold antialiased'><div class='w-2/3 flex justify-end'>"+objofproduct[i].brandName+" "+objofproduct[i].modelName+" "+objofproduct[i].tipName+"</div><div class='w-1/3 productcode font-light text-sm flex justify-start'>"+objofproduct[i].productCode+"</div></div><div class='text-lg'><b>» رنگ:</b> "+objofproduct[i].colorName+" <br> <b>» توضیحات:</b> "+objofproduct[i].description+"<br></div></div></div>";
                // تعیین ساختار مادر ایکس و کدی که باید هر بار اضافه شود
                $("#productx").append(productitem);
                // افزودن یک عدد به متغیر فرضی
                i = i + 1 ;
            })
            // پایان لوپ آیتم هر شهر

        },
        // پایان موفقیت
```